# Project 3D point to 2D screen coordinate

Tags: python, opengl, kivy, projection

I'm trying to project a few 3d points to screen coordinates to determine whether a touch occurs in roughly the same area. It should be noted that I'm doing this in Kivy, which is Python and OpenGL. I've seen questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697014/projecting-a-3d-point-to-2d-screen-coordinate-opentk), but I still don't have a solution. I've tried the following, but the numbers are not close to screen co-ordinates.

```
def to2D(self, pos, width, height, modelview, projection):
    p = modelview*[pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], 0])
    p = projection*p
    a = p[0]
    b = p[1]
    c = p[2]
    a /= c
    b /= c
    a = (a+1)*width/2.
    b = (b+1)*height/2.
    return (a, b)
```

To illustrate that this doesn't produce good results, take the following parameters

```
modelview = [[-0.831470, 0.553001, 0.053372, 0.000000],
             [0.000000, 0.096068, -0.995375, 0.000000],
             [-0.555570, -0.827624, -0.079878, 0.000000],
             [-0.000000, -0.772988, -2.898705, 1.000000]]
projection = [[ 15.763722, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000],
              [ 0.000000, 15.257052, 0.000000, 0.000000],
              [ 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.002002, -2.002002],
              [ 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000]]
pos = [0.523355213060808, -0.528964010275341, -0.668054187020413] #I'm working on a unit sphere, so these are more meaningful in spherical coordinates
width = 800
height = 600
```

With these parameters, `to2D` gives screen coordinates of (1383, -274)

I don't think the problem is related to OpenGL and python, rather to the operations involved in getting from 3d to screen coordinates.
**What I'm trying to do:** When a touch occurs, project a 3d point to 2d screen coordinates.

**My idea:**
Take the camera's modelview and projection matrices, a point that I'm interested in, and the touch position, and then make a method to get from the point to the touch position. Get the method, by converting [this source code for gluProject](http://collagefactory.blogspot.ca/2010/03/gluproject-source-code.html) into Python

**How I've done it:**

1. Take all of the mathematical objects into Sage for computational simplicity.
2. My touch position is (150, 114.1)
3. `modelview = matrix([[ -0.862734, 0.503319, 0.048577, 0.000000 ], 
                       [ 0.000000, 0.096068, -0.995375, 0.000000 ],
                       [ -0.505657, -0.858744, -0.082881, 0.000000 ],
                       [ 0.000000, -0.772988, -2.898705, 1.000000 ]])`
4. `projection = matrix([[ 15.763722, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000 ],
                        [ 0.000000, 15.257052, 0.000000, 0.000000 ],
                        [ 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.002002, -2.002002 ],
                        [ 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000 ]])`
5. `width = 800.`
6. `height = 600.`
7. `v4 = vector(QQ, [0.52324, -0.65021, -0.55086, 1.])`
8. `p = modelview*v4`
9. `p = projection*p`
10. `x = p[0]
     y = p[1]
     z = p[2]
     w = p[3]`
11. `x /= w
     y /= w
     z /= w`
12. `x = x*0.5 + 0.5
     y = y*0.5 + 0.5
     z = z*0.5 + 0.5`
13. `x = x*width
     y = y*height  #There's no term added because the widget is located at (0, 0)`

**The result:**

```
x = 15362.18
y = -6251.43
z = 10.14
```

**The revision:** Since this is not even close, I went back to steps 8 and 9 and switched the order of multiplication to see what would happen. So now 8. is `p = v4*modelview`, and 9. is `p = p*projection`. In this case, the vectors are row vectors. Another way of looking at this would be `p = modelviewTranspose*v4` and `p = projectionTranspose*p`, where the vectors are column vectors.

**The result Part 2:**

```
x = 150.29
y = 196.15
z = 0.6357
```

Recall that the goal is (150, 114.1). The x coordinate is very good, but the y coordinate is not. So I looked at `y*z`, which is 124.69. I could live with this answer, although I'm not sure if looking at `y*z` is what I should actually be doing

Comment: Can you give some example of input and output showing how what you get is not what you expect?

Comment: Maybe you're getting your modelview or projection wrong.
There's no guarantee of values put into either one fitting on your screen, or being clearly discernable even if they do fit on screen.

Comment: @TimothyGroote I get the modelview and projection matrices from the camera, so I don't see that being an issue.

Comment: @khelwood see edits.

Comment: `p = modelview*[pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], 0])` throws a SyntaxError due to the paren, and without the paren it throws a TypeError.

Comment: @Ryan, my mistake. I'd taken the matrices into Sage to do some calculating, so that line was originally ``p = modelview*Vector(QQ, [pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], 0])``. I must have forgotten to remove the ")"

Comment: Your matrices look very suspicious to me. Actually, your modelview matrix looks like the last 4 values in the code are the translation part. However, your projection matrix looks as if it is transposed to that, i.e. that (0 0 -2 0) should actully be the translation part. It looks like you use two different conventions for both.

Comment: @derhass I don't know the "how" behind the matrices; I just get them and try to do math on them. If I understand the way kivy3 (what I'm using for 3d) works, the ``modelview`` is calculated from something similar to ``gluLookAt``. ``projection`` is calculated from [Kivy's perspective function](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.transformation.html#kivy.graphics.transformation.Matrix.perspective) What would be your suggestion to fix the convention issues? I've found that looking at the transposes of each matrix gives better results, but I have no reason why.

Comment: @PistolPete: your numbers simply don't make sense. If I intrepret the modelview and projection matrices the way they should be interpreted, I get a poit which lies outside the frustum. I get the same numbers as you if I use the projection matrix transposed to what it actually should be. But the most interesting question to me is: how did you even come up with that input position vector (`v4`) in the frist place?

Comment: v4 comes from what I'm trying to do: when a touch occurs, project a specific set of 3d points to screen coordinates to see if the point is close to the touch. My (x, y, z) seems really arbitrary, but it's a point on a unit sphere, which is what I'm working on. So if the matrices are transposed, then their interpretations are correct? That makes some sense, since the answers I get with the transposes are close to being correct, but the original way that I was trying is awful.

Comment: @PistolPete: "v4 comes from what I'm trying to do: when a touch occurs, project a specific set of 3d points to screen coordinates to see if the point is close to the touch." That doesn't make sense. To get v4, you'll have to do the inverse, getting from your touch location to an object space point (often called "unprojecting"). Is that what you really want to do?

Comment: I've got a set of "special" points that are known ahead of time. That's how I know what v4 is. I project each one and see where they fall in relation to the touch position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68033/discussion-between-derhass-and-pistol-pete).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem is here:

```
p = modelview*[pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], 0])
```

When you multiple vector with matrix as 4component vector, Last component (`w`) **must** be 1.0

Another one is here:

```
c = p[2]
a /= c
b /= c
```

Instead of dividing x and y by z you should divide x, y AND z by w. w is p[4].

In addition to that:

When in doubt, find source code of `gluProject` and `gluUnproject`, tear it apart and convert to python.

As far as I know, when projecting vector manually to screen, you're supposed to do following:

1. Convert "position" to **4** component vector, with .w component set to one.

   ```
   v4.x = v3.x
   v4.y = v3.y
   v4.z = v3.z
   v4.w = 1.0
   ```
2. Multiply 4component by matrices.
3. Then divide all components by w.

   ```
   v4.x /= v4.w
   v4.y /= v4.w
   v4.z /= v4.w
   ```

THEN you'll get screen coordinates within +-1.0 range for x and y. (z will be either within 0.0..1.0 or 0.0..-1.0, I forgot which in case of OpenGL).

The reason why w comes to play is because you can't divide via matrix multiplication, so when you need to divide x/y/z by something, you put it into w component, and division is performed after all the matrix multiplications. w also makes translation matrices possible. Any vector with w == 0 cannot be translated using translation matrices, only rotated around origin and deformed with affine transforms ("origin" means point zero of coordinate space - (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) point)

P.S. Also, I don't know how python handles integer to float conversions, but I'd replace  `a = (a+1)*width/2` with `a = (a+1.0)*width/2.0` to explicitly specify you're using floating point numbers here.

Comment: So I looked at ``gluProject`` source from [here](http://collagefactory.blogspot.ca/2010/03/gluproject-source-code.html), and tried converting to Python, but I got an ``v4.x = 10530`` and ``v4.y = -12220``. For no reason whatsoever, I changed ``p = modelview*v4`` and ``p = projection*p`` to ``p = v4*modelview`` and ``p = p*projection``. This gave ``x = 111, y = 276, z 0.6397``, and if I compare the touch position to ``x`` and ``y*z``, it's close, but just a little
 off. The touch position was (124, 162).

Comment: @PistolPete: Can you make [short self contained complete example](http://sscce.org/) and link it to your question? It might be something as trivial as multiplication order (meaning, depending on your matrix library modelview\*p and p\*modelview might produce different results), however people that don't have minimal working OpenGL app written a python (I don't have one, and don't feel like writting one, no offense), might not bother researching your problem further without working example. Just something that draws a dot and uses your subroutine with barebones opengl....

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to it, pyopengl's `gluProject(x, y, z)` returns screenspace x, y, z coordinates for the current context. (Other implementations might need more arguments and set pointers instead of returning!)